# Assign a command's output to a variable in a declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

The command in question:

```
stage('Stage 1') {

    environment {
        CYPRESS_VERSION = ""
    }
            
    steps {
        script {
            CYPRESS_VERSION = "\$(npm show cypress version)"
            print("$CYPRESS_VERSION")                    
        }
   }
}
```

The print outputs the text `npm show cypress version`

Where as if I use `CYPRESS_VERSION = sh "npm show cypress version"`, it outputs the version in the console logs (`6.1.0`), but it doesn't assign it to the variable.

The output of the above command is `null`.

How can I assign the output of the command (6.1.0) to the variable `CYPRESS_VERSION` please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the standard output of the `sh` command:

`CYPRESS_VERSION = sh(script: "npm show cypress version", returnStdout: true).toString().trim()`